# How to 'foreach' a column in a DataTable using C#?

Tags: c#, foreach

How do I loop through each column in a datarow using `foreach`?

```
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
MySQLProcessor.DTTable(mysqlCommand, out dtTable);

foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtTable.Rows)
{
    //foreach(DataColumn dc in dtRow)
}
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This should work:

```
DataTable dtTable;

MySQLProcessor.DTTable(mysqlCommand, out dtTable);

// On all tables' rows
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtTable.Rows)
{
    // On all tables' columns
    foreach(DataColumn dc in dtTable.Columns)
    {
      var field1 = dtRow[dc].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

I believe this is what you want:

```
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dtRow.ItemArray)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: ItemArray is what I was looking for. Didn't get it via intellisense.

Comment: Note that ItemArray is of type Object[], so dc should be typed Object, not DataColumn.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        if (row[column] != null) // This will check the null values also (if you want to check).
        {
               // Do whatever you want.
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can check this out. Use foreach loop over a DataColumn provided with your DataTable.

```
 foreach(DataColumn column in dtTable.Columns)
 {
     // do here whatever you want to...
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 // For each row, print the values of each column.
    foreach(DataRow row in dt .Rows)
    {
        foreach(DataColumn column in dt .Columns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
        }
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx

Comment: so you this will stay inside that specific row, thats the part that had me wondering about it?

Comment: yeap, you get the row => columns belong to datatable so you can get value of each column in the row.

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ you could do something like:

```
foreach (var data in from DataRow row in dataTable.Rows
                     from DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns
                          where
                              row[col] != null
                          select row[col])
{
    // do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int countRow = dt.Rows.Count;
int countCol = dt.Columns.Count;

for (int iCol = 0; iCol < countCol; iCol++)
{
     DataColumn col = dt.Columns[iCol];

     for (int iRow = 0; iRow < countRow; iRow++)
     {
         object cell = dt.Rows[iRow].ItemArray[iCol];

     }
}
```