# Iterate through DataTable and Update Database

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have the following code which accepts a DataTable and iterates through the properties, then saves the data. I am looking for a more efficient way of processing this so that I do not have to manually hard-code the ItemArray counts as well as the row names. Can anyone provide details on how I can improve this?

```
IList<account_dim_temp> a1 = new List<account_dim_temp>();
                foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
                {
                    account_dim_temp a = new account_dim_temp();
                    a.account_id = (string) row.ItemArray[0].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.canvas_id = (string) row.ItemArray[1].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.name = (string) row.ItemArray[2].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.depth = (string) row.ItemArray[3].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.workflow_state = (string) row.ItemArray[4].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.parent_account = (string) row.ItemArray[5].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.parent_account_id = (string) row.ItemArray[6].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.grandparent_account = (string) row.ItemArray[7].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.grandparent_account_id = (string) row.ItemArray[8].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.root_account = (string) row.ItemArray[9].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.root_account_id = (string) row.ItemArray[10].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount1 = (string) row.ItemArray[11].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount1_id = (string) row.ItemArray[12].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount2 = (string) row.ItemArray[13].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount2_id = (string) row.ItemArray[14].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount3 = (string) row.ItemArray[15].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount3_id = (string) row.ItemArray[16].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount4 = (string) row.ItemArray[17].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount4_id = (string) row.ItemArray[18].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount5 = (string) row.ItemArray[19].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount5_id = (string) row.ItemArray[20].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount6 = (string) row.ItemArray[21].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount6_id = (string) row.ItemArray[22].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount7 = (string) row.ItemArray[23].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount7_id = (string) row.ItemArray[24].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount8 = (string) row.ItemArray[25].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount8_id = (string) row.ItemArray[26].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount9 = (string) row.ItemArray[27].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount9_id = (string) row.ItemArray[28].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount10 = (string) row.ItemArray[29].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount10_id = (string) row.ItemArray[30].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount11 = (string) row.ItemArray[31].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount11_id = (string) row.ItemArray[32].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount12 = (string) row.ItemArray[33].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount12_id = (string) row.ItemArray[34].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount13 = (string) row.ItemArray[35].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount13_id = (string) row.ItemArray[36].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount14 = (string) row.ItemArray[37].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount14_id = (string) row.ItemArray[38].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount15 = (string) row.ItemArray[39].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.subaccount15_id = (string) row.ItemArray[40].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a.sis_source_id = (string) row.ItemArray[41].ToString().Replace("\\N", "");
                    a1.Add(a);
                }
                db.account_dim_temp.AddRange(a1);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Use a constructor for `account_dim_temp` that takes a `DataRow` and does all your required logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [1] as suggestion:

```
// On all tables' rows
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtTable.Rows)
{
// On all tables' columns
   foreach(DataColumn dc in dtTable.Columns)
   {
       var field1 = dtRow[dc].ToString();
   }
}
```

[1] [How to 'foreach' a column in a DataTable using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939146/how-to-foreach-a-column-in-a-datatable-using-c)

Comment: `foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
                    {
                        assignment_group_dim_temp a = new assignment_group_dim_temp();
                        foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
                        {
                            string colName = column.ColumnName.ToString();
                            string colData = row[column].ToString();

                            **a.colName = colData;**
                            
                          agd.Add(a);
                        }
                    }` How do I assign the value in the *?

Comment: I might have to re-ask this question since I can't get the code to format correctly in comments.

Comment: You could use a dictionary instead of an item array or you could replace the inner foreach loop with a for loop.

Comment: You could use a dictionary instead of an item array or you could replace the inner foreach loop with a for loop. With the for loop you can access the index in the row as well as in the item array.

Comment: But, even with a for loop, how can I assign the variable to my model (assignment_group_dim_temp)? (That is the line with the asterisk -- a.colName = colData)

Comment: Something like this: a[i] = colData;
but this requires that the order of your attributes is the same as column ordering. A dictionary or a other built-in type with a name indexer would be much better. You could also add an name indexer by your own [1].

Answer (score 0):

**How Do I assign the values within the loop in the asterisk? Is this possible?**

```
 foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
                {
                    assignment_group_dim_temp a = new assignment_group_dim_temp();
                    foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
                    {
                        string colName = column.ColumnName.ToString();
                        string colData = row[column].ToString();

                        //How can I assign the following variable?
                        **a.colName = colData;**

                        agd.Add(a);
                    }
                }
```